# joomla 3.0 site component access control

Tags: joomla, frontend, acl, joomla3.0

Joomla 3 component security question (sorry noob). I've got a component I'd like the site and admin portions to have different access setting. The Joomla example seem to focus on the admin security, specifically admin\access.xml.

Can I set group level access on the "site" side of my component? if so, how?

Thanks, this is the best document I've found, but I don't believe it addresses my question.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_ACL#Restricting_access_to_the_component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right document, if it works correctly in the backend already, you can use it in the frontend too. As the tutorial describes you have to add:

```
// Access check: is this user allowed to access the backend of this component?
if (!JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.manage', 'com_yourcomponent')){
   //pop the error below:
   return JError::raiseWarning(404, JText::_('JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR'));
}else{
   // [...] Stuff for restricted access here 
}
```

In place of `core.manage` you can put whatever acl requirement you need to check against. For example `core.edit`, `core.manage`, `core.yourown` etc. These access control conditions co-exist in the `admin/access.xml` file, there's no need to create a separate file for the frontend.

Comment: Thanks. What i didn't understand was that i wasn't setting permissions we are setting actions. And then you configure your component to assign action to groups. Finally, users are in groups.

The key was adding the 'com_yourcomponent'. 

Thanks again.